# Caching and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, caching

I have a question that is more related to how ASP.NET works and will try my best to explain so here goes.

I have a four tiered architecture in my app

1. Web (ASP.NET Web Application)
2. Business (Class Library)
3. Generic CRUD layer ** (Class Library)
4. Data (Class Library)

This generic CRUD layer of mine uses reflection to set and read properties of an object, however I have read that using PropertyInfo is fairly expensive and thus want to cache these items.

Here is the scenario:

Two people access the site, lets call them Fred and Jim. Fred creates a Customer which in turn called the Generic CRUD layer and caches the property info of the Customer class within System.RuntimeCache. Jim, then seconds later also creates a Customer.

My question is will the two requests from both Fred and Jim cause the obtaining of propery info to be triggered twice? Or will ASP.NET retrieve it from cache the second time, i.e. Jim's request is quicker as property info is obtained via the cache?

My thinking is that because my CRUD is a class library and not having access to System.Web.Cache, the property info won't be cached across all sessions / users?

Comment: "Jim's request is quicker"... but if it came from cache, would it be correct? Would it matter if they shared a cached customer?

Comment: Don't optimize just because you've read that using PropertyInfo is fairly expensive. Wait until you need to optimize and then find the bottlenecks using profiling. Premature optimization is almost always a waste of time. Also, you're concerned that using PropertyInfo is slow, but your solution just avoids repeated calls to GetPropertyInfo(), however you'll still be using it just the same, with calls to SetProperty() every time you do an update.

Comment: Are there alternatives to using propertyinfo by any chance? I guess I am going to run some diagnostics in using this over a large collection of data and analyse the results. *EDIT just noticed something called Reflection.Emit, anyone used this as an alternative?*

Comment: The best alternative to using PropertyInfo.SetValue() is to just set the value in code. Having to use reflection to simply set lots of values in a data access layer is a very bad code smell and really suggests a fundamental design issue, or at least the wrong choice of language for the job.

Comment: Surely thats how a lot of ORM tools do this? They use reflection to set property values? I've been using this approach for a fair few months now and as long as the class is mapped correctly by some means (XML file etc) I found there are no issues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alexei Levenkov points out, you have to configure caching to happen explicitly: you're not going to get automatic caching of specific property values.

But let me point out that while using PropertyInfo is expensive compared to writing code to directly access properties, it pales in comparison to the cost of a database round-trip or the latency between your server and your end user. Tools like Entity Framework, WebForms, and MVC all make extensive use of reflection because the performance cost it incurs is totally worth the reduced maintenance costs.

Avoid premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will issue new queries for each request (unless you've coded otherwise).

There are multiple layers of caching that could happen in ASP.Net application (browser, proxies, server side response caching, intermediate objects caching, DA layer caching) which all can be configured/used. But nothing is ever cached in ASP.Net (or in any application) unless one specifically wrote code/rules/configuration to do so.